# Node, Mongoose - Referencing Document not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app, users can create posts. I want to assign a user to each  post by referencing the users `ObjectId`.

**Post model and schema**:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postImage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    caption: {
        type: String
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

User model and Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 75
  }
})

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = () => { 
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
  return token
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

In my post route, I apply the following middleware (auth middleware):

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token')
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send('No token provided')

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    }
    catch (ex) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid token')
    }
}
```

Post route:

```
router.post('/', [auth, upload.single('postImage')], async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        postImage: `http://localhost:3000/${req.file.path}`,
        caption: req.body.caption,
        user: req.user._id
    })

    await post.save()
    res.send(post)
})
```

When I make a request to the route, I set `x-auth-token`, and I get a response of the post object created. However in the database the `user` property on the post object has not been set . Only the following properties have been set on the post object created. `_id, date, postImage, caption, __v`. Does anybody know why the user is not being set as a property? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
This is how I generate the jwt token, with _id attached:

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = () => { 
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
  return token
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the `req.user` property in your post route, I believe its undefined

Comment: @KunalMukherjee If you look at my post, in the auth middleware, I write this line of code: `req.user = decoded`, however req.user is undefined as I print it to the console. Do you know why this is?

Comment: did you debug the auth middleware to check whether its actually attaching to request object or not ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee When I log req.user, I get {iat: 29283}, but when I log req.user._id I get undefined

Comment: So your token must have the `_id` property, if its not present it will be undefined and mongoose wont simply skip that field

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Please check my updated post. This is how I generate my token with _id attached

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I have just noticed that this is a user schema and not a post  schema method. The post is the object I am creating. Do you think this is why an _id is not being attached? Or does this not matter?